# Grappling a creature that is grappling another creature

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple

If creature B is grappling creature A, then creature C grapples creature B, can creature C move creature B at half movement as per grappling rules on PHB 195? If so, would that automatically break the B-A grapple or would A be grappled as well?

This came up in a game where the Druid turned into a giant squid, grappled an enemy, and then a Roc grappled and pulled the Druid off the boat. DM played it that the enemy was pulled up into the air with the Roc→giant squid combo to humorous results, but I was wondering about the actual ruling.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the B-A grapple would be broken, as specified by the details of the Grappled condition in Appendix A of the Player's Handbook

> The condition also ends if an effect removes the grappled creature from the reach of the grappler or grappling effect, such as when a creature is hurled away by the thunderwave spell. (PHB, 290)

Comment: Providing C had the strength to move be B if using encumberance

Comment: Well, encumbrance still lets you to go up to your max carrying capacity of 15 times your strength, and a Roc has 28 Strength, for a carry capacity of 420 pounds. Google search turns up the average weight of a giant squid at 440 pounds. However, push drag and lift allows for up to double your carrying capacity, for 840 pounds, but it also reduces speed to 5 feet when they go over their carrying capacity.
For the Roc pulling them away, you can move a grappled creature at half your speed, unless they're at least 2 sizes smaller. So it depends on if the squid is Large or Huge.

Comment: @J Nason remember to double the carrying capacity for each size category above Medium. So the Roc actually has a carrying capacity of 420 x 8 = 3360 pounds.